# Yellow Dog Linux 6.1 and PS3 GameOS Versions?

Tags: linux, cell, firmware, playstation3

I'm working on installing linux on a PS3 to do some development work and I've run across a bit of a snag. The current version of the firmware on my PS3 is 2.50. The Yellow Dog website [specifically mentions](http://us.fixstars.com/support/advisories.shtml) that there are problems with this release. The [official Yellow Dog install guide](http://us.fixstars.com/support/installation/ydl6.0_ps3_guide.pdf) (PDF!) also mentions that I should update my PS3 to the newest version (which is now 2.60). So does any body have any experience with this?

Comment: Erm, update the firmware like it says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I updated the firmware to 2.60 and everything seems to work (other than some network stuff, but I think that is specific to my environment, not this configuration of distro/ps3).